# Eclipse - Java - Selection does not contain a main type - git clone

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, github

I cloned a project into eclipse.

The directory structure is correct, it works properly in the project creator's computer.

I get the error, "Selection does not contain a main type"

The folder hierarchy is

A ->> B(The project) ->> src (and everything else)

I cloned A.

What could the error be?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the class you are trying to run contains a main method.

```
public static void main (String[] args) { //code }
```

Then try the following way: 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuaVR.png)

Comment: It contains that.

I tried doing it the same way when I first got the error.

Comment: Is there a bin folder (A --> bin) containing the .class files for all your classes including the main?

If not:
Option A: Delete the project re-clone it and re-import it.

Option B: Recompile the project by:

Project (deselect "Build Automatically") ->  Clean (Select your project and make sure you have enabled the option "start a build immediately").

Check if the .class files are generated.